# ways to maintain embedded YouTube videos watch time on my own site

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

To be clear, I'm not referring to the matrics from Youtube regarding any particular video. Rather, I want to do it just for my own site for some embedded videos.

What are the ways a counter like this could be implemented to count watch-time for embedded videos for any given site.

a solution better than this:---
The moment user's is on a Video page, get current timestamp and right before s/he leaves `onBeforeUnload`, calculate total time, cache it and later store it into the database against video id.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference is what you'll need.

Comment: thanks, you're spot on